# MSIX / Windows Application Packaging Project - After Publish event or target?

Tags: msix

So I have a Windows Application Packaging Project in Visual Studio which generates a MSIX installer. The AppInstaller URI points to an Amazon S3 bucket.

What I currently do is I first publish to a local drive, then upload the MSIX package to Amazon S3 via a bat file that calls the AWS command line interface.

I'd like this bat file to be automatically invoked via a kind of post-publish event or after publish target. However, I don't find any information if this can be done. I tried an AfterPublish target in the project file, but it seems this only works for ClickOnce projects, not MSIX ones.

Has somebody be able to automatically invoke commands after the publishing phase of an MSIX project completes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran down this rabbit hole to find a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/26710) where someone from Microsoft says:

> This appears to be because BeforePublish and AfterPublish are only defined for Web SDK projects, not the .NET SDK itself.

As this is not really an *answer*, either me or someone else can update this answer when it is supported in SDK projects.

*(Long live the Framework4.8)*